# Clojure, contains?/get on a set

Tags: clojure

`contains?` tells you whether `get` will succeed. I would also like to think that `get` returns something that comes from the collection, in this case a `set`.

```
(def all-match-okay #{
                 #{[3 0] [0 5]}
                 #{[2 4] [0 5]}})

(defn joinable? [b1 b2]
  (let [in-a-set (set [b1 b2])
        res (contains? all-match-okay in-a-set)]
    res))

(defn join [b1 b2]
  (let [in-a-set (set [b1 b2])
        res (get all-match-okay in-a-set)]
    (first res)))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (println (joinable? [0 5] [3 0]))
  (println (join [0 5] [3 0]))
  )
```

If you run the above code then `true` will come back from `joinable?` but `[0 5]` will come back from `join`. This means that what is in the collection is not being returned, but rather what got the match.

I'm sure what is happening here is theoretically correct (after all if they match it should not matter which is returned). But on the other hand returning what is actually in the set would also be theoretically fine. Would it not?

Comment: A successful `get` returns its second argument: it is an `identity` on its first (set) argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `(first res)` call.  You get a random element of the set, since they are not ordered. An (hopefully repeatable) example:

```
(second (apply hash-set (range 32)))
=> 7 (instead of 1)
```

clojure.core comes with a [sorted set](http://conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/1.7.0/clj/clojure.core/sorted-set/).  thirdparty libs (like e.g. [flatland](https://github.com/amalloy/ordered)) provide ordered sets.

Comment: I wonder if the sorted set will still match even if the two being compared have elements in different order, which is what I would be after.

Comment: I also wonder that an exception was not thrown instead of randomly choosing one. It is obviously wrong to be choosing the first of a collection that is not ordered.

Comment: to my knowledge sorted and hash sets are equals, if the elements are the same. i have not found a quote in the docs, that back this up. empirical test: `(= (apply hash-set (range 10000)) (apply sorted-set (range 10000)))`

Comment: That makes sense. Any jumbled up order in a set will equal any other differently jumbled up order in another set. As long as they have exactly the same elements in them they are equal. If this wasn't the case (even for *sorted* sets) then the world would be a strange place indeed, because a set would not be a set!

Comment: @cfrick see [here](http://clojure.org/data_structures#toc13). The [_Sets_](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#hashCode()) link seems to back up your (sensible in general) point.